# How to know the perm of the user when using ftplib?

Tags: python, ftp

I am using python module ftplib. Now I want to know whether the user has read, write, or create directory perm. How can I get the perm of current login user.

Answer (score 0):

retrlines('LIST') could be what you're looking for. It shows a dir listing and all permissions.
http://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.retrlines

Comment: that's the perm of files or directories, I want to know whether this user has write or delete perm. Does it work?

Comment: the permissions for the files and directories (. being the current dir) should let you know if the user is allowed to delete or write.

Comment: I made a little test. when the user has write permission, the permission bits are -rw-r--r--, and if not, the permission bits are -r--r--r--, but it highly depends on the files. If the ftp has no files, what shall I do?

Comment: if there are no files in the current dir you should still se the permissions for the current dir (.) no ?